# Debug iOS Safari html layout on Windows

Tags: ios, debugging, mobile-safari, markup

My ASP.NET MVC web site markup looks "wrong" in iOS (both iPad and iPhone). In desktop Safari Chrome, IE, etc. I just use and embedded developer tools in the browser to locate problems.

Is there a way to debug iOS Safari (via some emulator) from Windows. I also have Mac with xCode at hand, if it provides the ways to facilitate the process.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On your mac you can open the iOS Simulator (previously the iPhone simulator). If you have XCode you have the simulator. Just open the simulator, open Safari and navigate to your page from there, just as you would in a normal browser.

Since Mobile Safari doesn't have a capable HTML/CSS inspector [Firebug Lite](http://getfirebug.com/firebuglite) might work.

Comment: But does an emulator have a developer tools for debugging markup and js, like the desktop version of Safari has? It's not a problem to see the resulting layout, the problem is to see why it is being displayed that way.

Comment: It does not have the developer tools, but it can show you any errors in your CSS and JavaScript. I have found the error reporting to be really bad, but it's all you got. http://imgur.com/a/riABW If that doesn't do it maybe installing Firebug light will help? http://getfirebug.com/firebuglite/

Comment: Erik, you should edit your answer and add firebug lite info to it, since other options simple didn't do what I needed. I kind of forgot about FB Lite, I even had it pinned as a bookmark.

Comment: Firebug Lite - +1 for that.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is quite an old question, but since I run into this myself recently, and found a solution, let me share it here with anyone else that might come looking.

The [weinre](http://muellerware.org/papers/weinre/manual.html) project offers a remote debugger that works more or less like the old version of webkit dev tools. While it's not as fully featured as proper remote debugging tools found in Safari, it can get the job done when working with HTML and CSS.

The weinre package is available [on npmjs.com](https://www.npmjs.com/package/weinre) and it requires NodeJS / NPM installed on your system. It can debug any app running any browser, and works on all platforms where NodeJS is supported including Windows.

To install:

```
npm i -g weinre
```

Then start it on port 9000 (or whatever port you want):

```
weinre --httpPort 9000
```

Visiting localhost:9000 gives you access to instructions on how to instrument the web page you are testing (look under Target Script section). For example add this to your page:

```
<script src="http://localhost:9000/target/target-script-min.js#anonymous"></script>
```

Once the page is instrumented, you can go to the debug interface pointed to by the instructions page.